# Nuxt - Behaviour of Fetch lifecycle hook on page refresh

Tags: nuxt.js

I am not sure if this is expected behaviour, but in short, I have/ had a problem where my Universal-mode Nuxt app could not read from Firebase following a refresh of the page. This is because the request came from the server and therefore was being seen by Firebase as an unauthenticated user. I worked around it by forcing SPA mode on the affected page, and it works, but I don't like it as a solution.

Reason this happened is that I was/ am using the Firebase client library (So making the call from the client). I am using Nuxt's `fetch()` hook to invoke the read action. I used the client library as I (perhaps naively) assumed that this was better for page performance.

To stop refresh failing I should be (I believe) appending `fetchOnServer: false` to the fetch hook as per the Nuxt docs.

However this does not solve the issue.

I suspect this is because a refresh is not invoking Nuxt/ Vue functions in the same way as navigating to the page via the Nuxt router does. Is this correct? (I can see  even with `fetchOnServer` set to False `fetch()` still causes server- side requests to Firebase, which fail, as expected). Is there another way around this other than forcing SPA on the page as above? If not, I may look at using the Firebase-Admin library.

Appreciate any feedback on this.

EDIT: Here is an example query I am running in SPA mode currently - this returns all events that a given user is allowed to access. The result is returned to Vuex for client rendering of course :)

````js
  async getListOfEvents(uid) {
    fireDb = firebase.firestore()
    await firebase.auth().currentUser
    const pList = fireDb
      .collection('presentations')
      .where('usersWithPerms', 'array-contains', uid)
      .where('status', '==', 'ACTIVE-VISIBLE')
    try {
      const messageDoc = await pList.get()
      const aVP = []
      let rObj = {}
      messageDoc.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        const o = childSnapshot.data()
        rObj.pName = o.eventName
        rObj.synopsis = o.synopsis
        rObj.urlSlug = o.urlSlug
        rObj.owner = o.owner === uid
        aVP.push(rObj)
        rObj = {}
      })
      return aVP
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error during getting LIST of events! ${e}`)
    }
  },```
````

Comment: Could you please go a bit further on exactly the type of query you're trying to make? If you are making a simple query and trying to load the data in your page, I might have a solution for you. Also which version of nuxt are you using?

Comment: Hi there, Yes they are fairly simple queries (Just retrieving records from Firebase where the records match a user ID - I will update the original post with an example for you). I am using Nuxt  2.12.2. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the update, can you tell me how are you refreshing the page please?

Comment: At the moment just F5 or navigating directly to it - basically anything that avoids Nuxt-Router being invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I completely understand your problem, but I imagine that you want to fetch the data from firebase just on the client on a specific page.

So, you could do this: Call your method on some vue lifeCycle method like created() or mounted() and add `process.browser` validation. Something like that:

```
created() {
  if (process.browser) {
    // fetch from firebase
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer- yes this had occurred to me, but ideally I want to make the queries on the server side. Maybe I am misguided, but I feel it gives me a shot at better SEO/ performance than effectively running in a 'SPA-like' state. I am not sure it has any additiona securityl benefit such as obfuscating my query structure, as even in SSR I believe Nuxt still delivers the entire page to the client in Universal mode - correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So in the end the cleanest way to get around this was to just go ahead and use 'Nuxt Firebase' https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started/

It requires a Service Worker and therefore Nuxt PWA to work properly, but the results are very satisfactory.

I am also not a huge fan of the fact the Firebase services you enable are within global scope using this, but so far I have found very little negative impact on app performance. (Running tests via Lighthouse)